# Coloring table cells in D3 v4

Tags: css, html, d3.js

I've recently been trying to upgrade my code of several d3.js things I've written a long time ago to be compatible with the newer version 4 of d3.js.

One of my modules uses the .attr("bgcolor",....) to set and dynamically color individual cells in an html table to change in accordance with the value of a number in the cell.  After upgrading to version 4 of d3.js, I had to change a few syntax things, and mostly have the format displaying, but I can't get the colors to function at all.  I've explored all the colorspaces (hsl, rgb, etc.), and all of them consistently display really dark colors.

One thing that has me worried is [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp), which says that setting "bgcolor" for a `<td>` element is not supported in html5.  Not sure if that applies here or not, but is this method of applying a "bgcolor" attribute to `<td>` cells no longer a valid one?

Here is how the module functions properly using d3 v3.  Any ideas how I would modify this module to work properly with v4?
https:  https://knowhuddle.com/teamstats/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `.attr("bgcolor",....)`, use `.style("background-color", ...)`

Comment: Also, you are going to need to create a small reproducible example of your question.  I doubt anyone is going to be willing to wade through the code on your website to figure it out....

Comment: To answer the question: yes, W3Schools is right, bgcolor was declared invalid long ago. [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor) is an official document from 1998 saying it was deprecated. Since then, styles have been the way to go. Not that bgcolor will stop working in the browsers any time soon though...

Comment: Anyway, the problem of really dark colors if you use rgb rather than #'d colors, could that be a hex/dec mismatch? For instance, rgb(90,90,90) is darker than #909090. If that's not it, you should create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.